# How to put datasets created by torchvision.datasets in GPU in one operation?

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, pytorch, torchvision

I’m dealing with CIFAR10 and I use torchvision.datasets to create it. I’m in need of GPU to accelerate the calculation but I can’t find a way to put the whole dataset into GPU at one time. My model need to use mini-batches and it is really time-consuming to deal with each batch separately.

I've tried to put each mini-batch into GPU separately but it seems really time-consuming.

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR

You won't save time by moving the entire dataset at once.

---

I don't think you'd necessarily want to do that even if you have the GPU memory to handle the entire dataset (of course, CIFAR10 is tiny by today's standards).

I tried various batch sizes and timed the transfer to GPU as follows:

```py
num_workers = 1 # Set this as needed

def time_gpu_cast(batch_size=1):
    start_time = time()
    for x, y in DataLoader(dataset, batch_size, num_workers=num_workers):
        x.cuda(); y.cuda()
    return time() - start_time

# Try various batch sizes
cast_times = [(2 ** bs, time_gpu_cast(2 ** bs)) for bs in range(15)]
# Try the entire dataset like you want to do
cast_times.append((len(dataset), time_gpu_cast(len(dataset))))

plot(*zip(*cast_times)) # Plot the time taken
```

For `num_workers = 1`, this is what I got:
[image: Serial Processing Cast Times]

And if we try parallel loading (`num_workers = 8`), it becomes even clearer:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer and I'm gonna try it later. It seems promising.

> You can write a dataset class where in the **init** function, you red the entire dataset and apply all the transformations you need, and convert them to tensor format. Then, send this tensor to GPU (assuming there is enough memory). Then, in the **getitem** function you can simply use the index to retrieve the elements of that tensor which is already on GPU.